# Print a new list from a dictionary?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop

i am trying to find a way to print out a new list from an existing dictionary in python. I want to be able create a new list with each of the fabric types based off of the entries in the dictionary, instead of printing out the entire dictionary. I am still a beginner trying to figure it out. All other ways resulted in errors. Here is the code i have so far, but i feel there has to be an easier way than repeatedly breaking the loop for the same task. Any suggestions?

```
Clothes_in_Closet = [{
                "type" : "sweater",
                "fabric" : "wool", 
                "size" : "s", 
                
            }, 
            {    
                "type" : "shirt",
                "fabric" : "cotton", 
                "size" : "m", 
            },
            {
                "type" : "jeans",
                "fabric" : "cotton blend",
                "size" : "m", 
            }
                ]
newList = [ ]          

for fabrics in Clothes_in_Closet:
  fabrics = Clothes_in_Closet [0]["fabric"]
  newList.append(fabrics)
  break
for fabrics in Clothes_in_Closet:
  fabrics = Clothes_in_Closet [1]["fabric"]
  newList.append(fabrics)
  break
for fabrics in Clothes_in_Closet:
  fabrics = Clothes_in_Closet [2]["fabric"]
  newList.append(fabrics)
  break
print(newList)
```

Comment: What do you want

Comment: Instead of `break`ing, you could simply not do that and use `fabrics` wich will take on each inner dict - so you can do `for thing in Clothes_in_Closet: newList.append( thing["fabric"])`

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension and grab the value associated with key `fabric`:

```
newList = [cloth['fabric'] for cloth in Clothes_in_Closet]
print(newList)
```

Output:

```
['wool', 'cotton', 'cotton blend']
```

You can use the traditional looping approach as well instead of list comprehension but note that list comprehension is preferred over traditional looping in Python:

```
newList = []
for cloth in Clothes_in_Closet:
    newList.append(cloth['fabric'])
    
print(newList)
```

Comment: further apply `set()` to the result as `set(newList)` if you need only the unique values.